# In android studio,How to rectify the error "E/Zygote: no v2" while fetching html content from url link?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to android studio and I tried to get html content of a webpage using AsyncTask class(deprecated API).I have attached my AndroidManifest.xml file. I have added the neccessary permisions to access internet,still i am getting the error "E/Zygote : no v2" and my app crashes. Please explain what does this error mean and how to eliminate the error.I launched the app in a phone with Android 6.0.1

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String result ="";
            URL url;
            HttpsURLConnection urlConnection;
            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);
                urlConnection =(HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
                int data = reader.read();
                while(data!=-1){
                    char current = (char) data;
                    result += current;
                    data = reader.read();
                }
                return result;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

But the LogCat came up with this error

> [08-11 11:46:36.426 27036-27036/? E/Zygote: no v2

> 08-11 11:46:36.426 27036-27036/? W/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, index[1], priority [2], priority version is VE=SEPF_SECMOBILE_6.0.1_0035

> 08-11 11:46:36.436 27036-27036/? W/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=default, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.example.guessthecelebrity

> 08-11 11:46:36.436 27036-27036/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni

> 08-11 11:46:36.827 27036-27036/com.example.guessthecelebrity D/ResourcesManager: For user 0 new overlays fetched Null

> 08-11 11:46:36.847 27036-27036/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.guessthecelebrity-2/lib/arm

> 08-11 11:46:36.907 27036-27036/com.example.guessthecelebrity D/ResourcesManager: For user 0 new overlays fetched Null

> 08-11 11:46:36.927 27036-27036/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.guessthecelebrity">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permissioandroid:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Kotlin's **coroutines** is a better alternative for AysncTask. Coroutines is a bit complicated for beginners, but if you want to use third-party alternatives then you may find many in Java.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, BlackList96.I am a beginner and learning app development through online course.I tried to fetch html content in my app .But i am unable to rectify the error "E/Zygote : no v2" and also the App crashes. I have tried searching almost everywhere in internet.But couldn't able to fix this error. Can you help me to know about this error and how to eliminate it.

Comment: Which webpage you are trying to get?

Comment: I tried with this webpage (https://www.forbesindia.com/lists/2019-celebrity-100/1819/all). Somehow found that the error i mentioned, is nothing to bother about. And i tried BufferedReader instead of InputStreamReader. But, I am not getting the complete html content.It displays only a partial part of the content.

Comment: Have you tried my solution?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not good at using AsyncTask. You are not executing the AsyncTask anywhere. How ever, a better clean approach will be as follows,

**XML**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/url_request"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Input a web page url to get." />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/url_request_btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Request Page"
            android:onClick="downloadSiteData"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/url_response"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity with AsyncTask:**

```java
package com.example.downloadsite;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText urlRequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        urlRequest = findViewById(R.id.url_request);
    }


    public void downloadSiteData(View view) {

        String url = urlRequest.getText().toString();

        if ( url.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "URL can't be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            new DownloadTask().execute(url);
        }
    }

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Downloading site data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String value = urls[0];
            String response = null;

            URL url = null;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            InputStream in = null;

            try {
                url = new URL(value);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                response = readStream(in);

            } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

            finally {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }

            return response;
        }

        private String readStream(InputStream inputStream) {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            try {

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String nextLine = "";
                String newLine = "";

                while ((newLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(nextLine + newLine);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

            return sb.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String responseString) {
            super.onPostExecute(responseString);

            TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.url_response);
            tv.setText(responseString);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No ,Actually, here i didn't post the part of code where i am executing AsyncTask. I wasn't having any problem with my code.Only that error and warnings bothered me.Somehow I found that those error and warnings are nothing to bother about. Now i am getting the HTML content clearly. Anyway, Thanks for your suggestions.